# How to override styles with higher specificity - styled components

Tags: styled-components

I read styled components docs and know the basics how to override some styles, but I can't figure out this in my case.

I need to override some class in my div

So my structure looks like this:

How Can I achieve this with higher specificity from styled components instead `!important`

```js
export const SomeDiv = styled.div`
  .someClassName  {
    left: ${(props) => props.left || 0} !important;
    ${(props) =>
    props.top &&
    `
         top ${props.top} !important;
    `}
  }
 `
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const SomeDiv = styled.div`
  .someClassName {
    &&& {
      left: ${(props) => props.left || 0} !important;
      ${(props) =>
      props.top &&
      `
           top ${props.top} !important;
      `}
    }
  }
 `
```

[Github issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components-website/issues/187#issuecomment-451705900)

Comment: How styled component knows that I want to set bellow styles for this someClassName  class